# Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_{18}$ be the vertices of a regular polygon with 18 sides. How many of the triangles $A_iA_jA_k$ are isosceles but not equilateral?

Tags: combinatorics, fake-proofs

Let $A_1,A_2,.....,A_{18}$ be the vertices of a regular polygon with $18$ sides. How many of the triangles $\Delta A_iA_jA_k,1\le i<j<k\le 18$, are isosceles but not equilateral?

My Attempt:

We consider a regular $18-$ gon. If we have to choose the vertex of an  isoceles triangle, we find that we have $18$ possible vertices (of the polygon) to choose from. Now, we choose a particular vertex and label it $0$ and the 1st 9 vertices to the left of $0$ as $1,2,3,...,9$ respectively and the first $8$ vertices from the right of $0$ as $-1,-2,...,-8$ respectively. So, we find that, if we choose any vertex $|i|$ (,where $i\in\{1,2,...,8,-1,...,-8\}$) then the only possible choice of the third vertex should be $\text{sign}(-i)(|i|)$ so that three vertices forms an isosceles triangle. But then, we can't choose the vertex $9$ as, then, whichever vertex we choose as the third vertex of the desired triangle, the triangle won't ever be an isoceles one. So, we see, that we can choose the 2nd vertex $i$ of the isosceles triangle in $8$ ways and for each possible choice of $i$ the third vertex becomes fixed.( So, we see, that the remaining two vertices of the isoceles triangle can be any of the $8$ possible pairs $(1,-1),(2,-2),...,(8,-8)$.) So, the total number of ways to generate isosceles triangles is $18.8=144$ ways.

However, the answer given is $18.7=126$ isoceles triangles are possible. I find my way of solving reasonable, and don't appear to have any errors to me. It would be helpful, if anyone points out the mistake I made.

Comment: Among $(1,-1),(2,-2),...,(8,-8)$, you have to eliminate $(6,-6)$ which gives an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, ok, that was ridiculous! How couldn't I think of this! Will you add that as an answer, or if you insist I may add it as an answer. But it's better if you write it, cause comments seems to get deleted.

Comment: Thanks. A very small answer, but as you say, in this way the question has an answer... I will add the general case for an n-gon...

Comment: @JeanMarie Wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among $(1,−1),(2,−2),...,(8,−8)$, you must eliminate $(6,−6)$ which gives an equilateral triangle.

For the general case of a $n$-gon :

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n&\text{mult. of }2&\text{mult. of }3&Formula\\
\hline
&T&T&n(\frac{n-2}{2}\color{red}{-1})\\
&T&F&n(\frac{n-2}{2})\\
&F&T&n(\frac{n-1}{2}\color{red}{-1})\\
&F&F&n(\frac{n-1}{2})
\end{array}$$

(the $\color{red}{-1}$ meaning that we "uncount" the equilateral triangles)

Explanations for the first case, for example : if $n=6m$, with your notations, we can use numbering $(1,-1)... (3m-1,3m-1)$ minus case $(2m,-2m)$ (equilateral triangle) giving a total number $6m(3m-2).$

Comment: The $n\equiv3\pmod6$ case should be $3(2m+1)(3m)=n(n-3)/2$ (to uncount the equilaterals), and the case $n\not\equiv0\pmod 3$ should be $n\lceil \frac n2-1\rceil$ (otherwise you’re counting the degenerate diagonals in the even case).

Comment: (Or in a single expression, $$n\cdot\left(\left\lceil\frac n2-1\right\rceil - [3\mid n]\right),$$ where $[]$ is the Iverson bracket.)

Comment: @Milten You are right, I will fix it. Besides, please, transform your formula into an answer that I will be happy to upvote.

Comment: Sure, done :) ${        }$

Comment: Similar but not the same : https://oeis.org/A320577

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already an answer I give an alternative solution for $6n$ gon.

Let $a$ be the number of equlateral triangles (so $a=2n$) and $b$ all other isoscseles triangles. Color all vertices $1,3,5,...,6n-1$ red and all others blue.

Connect given triangle with pair of vertices of the same color iff they form it base.
Then every equalteral is connected with 3 monocolor pairs and isosceles with one monocolor pairs. On the other hand each monocolor pair is connected with 2 triangles. Since all monocolor pairs is $2\cdot {3n\choose 2}$ we have $$3a+b=2\cdot  2\cdot {3n\choose 2} \implies \boxed{b = 6n(3n-2)}$$

So in particulary $b=124$ for $n=3$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\liver{[\![}\newcommand\river{]\!]}$This is a compression of Jean Marie's answer into a single, fairly simple formula for the general case.

There are $n$ choices for the apex (what OP calls the vertex). For each of those, there are $\lceil n/2-1\rceil$ choices for the base (where the brackets mean ceiling). Finally, if $3$ divides $n$, exactly one of these will be equilateral, so we must uncount that one. Using an Iverson bracket $\liver \cdot\river$, we can write the general expression as

$$n\cdot\left(\left\lceil \frac n2-1\right\rceil - \liver 3\mid n\river\right).$$